# Bootstrap scroll spy doesn't work with either the javascript implementation or <body> element content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a fiddle of my project, a little simpler. But you can see that it is set up correctly and will not work at all, it does nothing.

https://jsfiddle.net/ybarpz3x/8/

I have been trying to debug this for 3 days and I just.... I just can't, it just doesn't work when it should. I've included jquery, bootstraps js, and bootstraps css obviously, I made my own .active class, and I've tried doing the `<body data-spy="scroll" .. >` and the javascript implementation which is on the jsfiddle.

Please help, thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Cache selectors
  var lastId,
      topMenu = $("#navmenu"),
      topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
      // All list items
      menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
      // Anchors corresponding to menu items
      scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) { return item; }
      });

  // Bind click handler to menu items
  // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
  menuItems.click(function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
        offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 300);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  var navHeight = $("#navmenu").outerHeight(true) ;

  // Bind to scroll
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    // Get container scroll position
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+navHeight;

    var navCollapse = 450;

    if (fromTop > navCollapse) {
      $("nav li").addClass("top-menu-collapsed")
    };

    if (fromTop <= navCollapse) {
      $("nav li").removeClass("top-menu-collapsed")
    };             
  });

  // Add scrollspy to <body>
});
$('window').load(function(){
  $('body').scrollspy({target: '#navmenu', offset: navHeight});
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700,800,900&subset=latin-ext";
.no-side-padding {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative; }

nav {
  text-align: right;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 999999;
}

nav ul {
  font-size: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  color: #337ab7;
}

nav ul .active {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #36B8C8;
}

nav ul .active a {
  color: #204E76;
}

nav ul .top-menu-collapsed {
  padding: 20px 24px;
}

nav ul * {
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 24px;
}

nav ul li a {
  position: static;
  z-index: 555555;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active, nav ul li a:focus, nav ul li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 666666;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 22 24;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

nav ul li:hover, nav ul li:active {
  cursor: hand;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #36B8C8;
}

nav ul li:hover a, nav ul li:active a {
  color: #204E76;
}

nav ul li.active:after {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #36B8C8;
}

nav ul li.active:after a {
  color: #204E76;
}

.colour-options {
  color: #36B8C8;
  color: #337ab7;
}

#options #chair-finishes-gallery ul {
  position: relative;
}

#options #chair-finishes-gallery ul li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 31%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 3%;
}

#options #chair-finishes-gallery ul li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#options #chair-finishes-gallery span {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 45%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  font-family: sans-serif, inherit;
}

#options #big-list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  columns: 5;
  -webkit-columns: 5;
  -moz-columns: 5;
  padding: 0;
}

#options #big-list ul li * {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#options #big-list ul #li-img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 28px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

@media (max-width: 995px) {
  #options #big-list ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    columns: 4;
    -webkit-columns: 4;
    -moz-columns: 4;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #options #big-list ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    columns: 3;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

#about1, #about2, #about3 {
  padding: 300px 100px;
}
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=ncss.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav id="thatnav">
  <ul id="navmenu" >
    <li><a href="#about1"><i style="padding-right: 5px;" class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a><div></div></li>
    <li><a href="#about2">Ordering</a><div></div></li>
    <li><a href="#about3" target="_blank">Designs</a><div></div></li>
    <li><a href="#hotels-resorts" target="_blank">Hotels / Resorts</a><div></div></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section style="background: rgba(50,50,50,1)" id="about1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-centered">
      <div style="color: #fff;" class="col-lg-8 col-centered">
        <h3 class="custom-h2">..now, about your Leisure</h3>
        <p class="custom-p">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sodales sit amet magna in ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed finibus, purus quis pellentesque suscipit, magna ipsum vulputate tortor, quis vehicula elit leo convallis erat. Suspendisse in dui bibendum diam facilisis suscipit ut tristique enim. Fusce eget lobortis odio. Ut non tortor ut mauris fermentum cursus eu ut eros. 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section style="background: rgba(50,50,50,1)" id="about2">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-centered">
      <div style="color: #fff;" class="col-lg-8 col-centered">
        <h3 class="custom-h2">..now, about your Leisure</h3>
        <p class="custom-p">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sodales sit amet magna in ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed finibus, purus quis pellentesque suscipit, magna ipsum vulputate tortor, quis vehicula elit leo convallis erat. Suspendisse in dui bibendum diam facilisis suscipit ut tristique enim. Fusce eget lobortis odio. Ut non tortor ut mauris fermentum cursus eu ut eros. 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section style="background: rgba(50,50,50,1)" id="about3">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-centered">
      <div style="color: #fff;" class="col-lg-8 col-centered">
        <h3 class="custom-h2">..now, about your Leisure</h3>
        <p class="custom-p">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sodales sit amet magna in ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed finibus, purus quis pellentesque suscipit, magna ipsum vulputate tortor, quis vehicula elit leo convallis erat. Suspendisse in dui bibendum diam facilisis suscipit ut tristique enim. Fusce eget lobortis odio. Ut non tortor ut mauris fermentum cursus eu ut eros. 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Bootstrap docs, scrollspy requires a Bootstrap 'nav' component to work. Read up on it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).